# Flutter: How can I get the RAM and Storage of a device with my app?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I need to get this kind of info trough my app. Doing a research I found the package device_info_plus, but that package don't show the info that I need, like RAM, storage, processor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the package called [disk_space](https://pub.dev/packages/disk_space) which gets you the total amount of storage available on your device

```
import 'package:disk_space/disk_space.dart';

void getDiskSpaceInfo() async{
  print(await DiskSpace.getFreeDiskSpace);
  print(await DiskSpace.getTotalDiskSpace);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for storage, but also I need the amount of RAM, do you know how I could get it?

Comment: As far as I know the only way to get ram info is through the package called system_info but I didn’t mention it in the answer because that package was discontinued

Comment: There is a package called [system_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/system_info_plus)